# CSS :after transition (on hover)

Tags: css

I am using **`:after`** to create a hover over design (long story, in WP with VC) and am not trying to get the **`:after`** CSS to fade in when someone hovers over the initial div.

Here is a fiddle - [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/slinger55/mnrnqykp/)

Below is my approach:

```
.border-home:hover:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/3Si5tIy.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: 190px 50px;
    content: '';
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(127, 165, 61, 0.9);
}
```

I am struggling to make the green background and read more button fade in smoothly.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: How about an animation with keyframes?

Comment: @Jojo How about a transition without keyframes? ;)

Comment: @connexo Oh, I dind't thought about the opacity. I tried to manipulate the Background-color directly with the transition and that didn't worked. So i thought an animation would be best.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add

```
.border-home::after {
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}

.border-home:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: Transitions are very easy and comfortable in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, connexo is right, this is a simple example on your code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnrnqykp/1/).

First you need to set your styling in `:after` (backgrounds, position etc) and some transition properties for opacity, and then just show it in `:hover:after` ;)

Comment: Thank you as well for providing the fiddle to get my head around it!

Answer (score 0):

The same as connexo

```html
.style::after {
    width: 0;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}

.style:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```